# XMLSerializer : Find element with name and attribute value

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xmlserializer

I am working to deserialize XML from a third party into a set C# classes. The classes will be used to populate another domain model. (ETL code)

Below is a partial example of the XML:

```
<Root>
    <Message>
        <Transaction>
            <Header group_element="2TRG00">2TRG212 7</Header>
            <TransactionStructureStandardVersionNumber group_element="2TRG01">98</TransactionStructureStandardVersionNumber>
            <ApplicationSoftwareRevisionLevel group_element="2TRG02"/>
            <TransactionImage group_element="2TRG03"/>
            <AutomationLevel group_element="2TRG04">3</AutomationLevel>
            <TransactionCategory group_element="2TRG05">P</TransactionCategory>
            <PolicyTypeRoutingCode group_element="2TRG06">P</PolicyTypeRoutingCode>
            <LineOfBusinessRoutingCode group_element="2TRG07">HOME</LineOfBusinessRoutingCode>
            <TransactionFunction group_element="2TRG08">FMG</TransactionFunction>
            <ProcessingCycleStatus group_element="2TRG09">B</ProcessingCycleStatus>
            <InitialTransactionMode group_element="2TRG10">N</InitialTransactionMode>
            <SpecialResponseOption group_element="2TRG11">0</SpecialResponseOption>
            <ErrorProcessingOption group_element="2TRG12"/>
            <FormalTransactionAddress group_element="2TRG13">IBM954UNIV</FormalTransactionAddress>
            <InformalTransactionAddress group_element="2TRG14">UNIVERSAL P&amp;C INS CO</InformalTransactionAddress>
            <FormalTransactionAddress group_element="2TRG15"/>
            <InformalTransactionAddress group_element="2TRG16"/>
            <SpecialHandling group_element="2TRG17">WEBCETERA</SpecialHandling>
            <OriginationReferenceInformation group_element="2TRG18"/>
            <TransactionSequenceNumber group_element="2TRG19">8249</TransactionSequenceNumber>
            <DeletedTransactionDate group_element="2TRG20">210217</DeletedTransactionDate>
            <ProcessingCycleNumber group_element="2TRG21">8249</ProcessingCycleNumber>
            <ReferenceTransactionSequenceNumber group_element="2TRG22"/>
            <DeletedTransactionEffectiveDate group_element="2TRG23">210228</DeletedTransactionEffectiveDate>
            <ResponseAutomationLevel group_element="2TRG24"/>
            <CycleBusinessPurpose group_element="2TRG25">REI</CycleBusinessPurpose>
            <SynchronizationField group_element="2TRG26"/>
            <SegmentLevelCode group_element="2TRG27"/>
            <SegmentedTransactionCounter group_element="2TRG28"/>
            <SegmentedTransactionTotalPieces group_element="2TRG29"/>
            <QuoteDate group_element="2TRG30"/>
            <DeletedYear2000LogicCode group_element="2TRG31">A</DeletedYear2000LogicCode>
            <TransactionDate group_element="2TRG32">20210217</TransactionDate>
            <TransactionEffectiveDate group_element="2TRG33">20210228</TransactionEffectiveDate>
        </Transaction>
    </Message>
</Root>
```

Two things:

1. Some of the element names are duplicated, like InformalTransactionAddress
2. Each element has an attribute named "group_element" with a unique value

Here is my current class (work in progress)

```
using Insurance_Carrer_Capture.API.Policy;
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using AcordAL3XMLParsingLibrary.Extensions;

namespace Insurance_Carrier_Capture.API.Core.Models.Policy
{
    public class Transaction : IPolicyVisitable
    {
        [XmlIgnore]
        public Message Parent{ get; set; }
        [XmlElement("PolicyTypeRoutingCode")] 
        public string PolicyTypeRoutingCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("LineOfBusinessRoutingCode")]
        public string LineOfBusinessRoutingCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TransactionFunction")]
        public string TransactionFunction { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("InformalTransactionAddress")] 
        public string InformalTransactionAddressSender { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TransactionSequenceNumber")]
        public int TransactionSequenceNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("TransactionDate")]
        public String TransactionDateStr
        {
            get { return TransactionDate.DateTimeToDateStr(); }
            set { this.TransactionDate = value.DateStrToDateTime(); }
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime TransactionEffectiveDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TransactionEffectiveDate")]
        public String TransactionEffectiveDateStr
        {
            get { return TransactionEffectiveDate.DateTimeToDateStr(); }
            set { this.TransactionEffectiveDate = value.DateStrToDateTime(); }
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public BasicInsuredInformationGroup BasicInsuredInformationGroup { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public BasicInsuredInformationExtensionGroup BasicInsuredInformationExtensionGroup { get; set; }

        public void Accept(IPolicyVisitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.VisitTransaction(this);
            //todo: other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

My question is about the InformalTransactionAddressSender property. It corresponds to the XML Element **InformalTransactionAddress** with the **group_element** value of "*2TRG14*". How can I make sure that the XMlSerilaizer picks that one and not the one with the value 2TRG16?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the desired element contains inner text, and the other one doesn't.

Below I'll show how to create the classes for the XML (complete code is at the end).

Given the following XML structure,

```
<Root>
    <Message>
        <Transaction>
             ...
        </Transaction>
    </Message>
</Root>
```

we'll use the following class names:

- Root:
- RootMessage: "Root" + "Message"
- RootMessageTransaction: "RootMessage" + "Transaction"

For any element beneath "Transaction", that contains a property, we'll create a class for it as well. We'll follow a similar naming strategy as above.

ex: `TransactionFunction` will have the following class name:  `RootMessageTransactionTransactionFunction`

**RootMessageTransactionTransactionFunction**:

```
public class RootMessageTransactionTransactionFunction
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
    public string group_element { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;

}
```

**Note**: If the element had more properties, we'd add them as well.

Given:

```
<TransactionFunction group_element="2TRG08">FMG</TransactionFunction>
```

The inner text is: FMG

**Usage**:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionFunction")]
public RootMessageTransactionTransactionFunction TransactionFunction { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionTransactionFunction();
```

Since both `FormalTransactionAddress` and `InformalTransactionAddress` occur more than once, we'll use a List for each of them. We'll also add the ability to sort descending on InnerText-which will put the element that contains a value in InnerText in index 0.

`FormalTransactionAddress` will have the following name: `RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress`

**RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress**:

```
public class RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress : IComparable<RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress>
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
    public string group_element { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int CompareTo(RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress other)
    {
        //sort desc

        if (String.Compare(this.InnerText, other.InnerText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (String.Compare(this.InnerText, other.InnerText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0)
        {
            return -1; //sort desc
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "FormalTransactionAddress")]
public List<RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress> FormalTransactionAddress { get; set; } = new List<RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress>();
```

---

Below is the complete code needed to deserialize the XML from the OP.

**Create a class** (name: RootMessageTransaction.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlSerialization6656
{
    public class RootMessageTransaction
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ApplicationSoftwareRevisionLevel")]
        public RootMessageTransactionApplicationSoftwareRevisionLevel ApplicationSoftwareRevisionLevel { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionApplicationSoftwareRevisionLevel();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AutomationLevel")]
        public RootMessageTransactionAutomationLevel AutomationLevel { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionAutomationLevel();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CycleBusinessPurpose")]
        public RootMessageTransactionCycleBusinessPurpose CycleBusinessPurpose { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionCycleBusinessPurpose();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DeletedTransactionDate")]
        public RootMessageTransactionDeletedTransactionDate DeletedTransactionDate { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionDeletedTransactionDate();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DeletedTransactionEffectiveDate")]
        public RootMessageTransactionDeletedTransactionEffectiveDate DeletedTransactionEffectiveDate { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionDeletedTransactionEffectiveDate();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DeletedYear2000LogicCode")]
        public RootMessageTransactionDeletedYear2000LogicCode DeletedYear2000LogicCode { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionDeletedYear2000LogicCode();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ErrorProcessingOption")]
        public RootMessageTransactionErrorProcessingOption ErrorProcessingOption { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionErrorProcessingOption();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FormalTransactionAddress")]
        public List<RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress> FormalTransactionAddress { get; set; } = new List<RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress>();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
        public RootMessageTransactionHeader Header { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionHeader();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "InformalTransactionAddress")]
        public List<RootMessageTransactionInformalTransactionAddress> InformalTransactionAddress { get; set; } = new List<RootMessageTransactionInformalTransactionAddress>();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "InitialTransactionMode")]
        public RootMessageTransactionInitialTransactionMode InitialTransactionMode { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionInitialTransactionMode();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LineOfBusinessRoutingCode")]
        public RootMessageTransactionLineOfBusinessRoutingCode LineOfBusinessRoutingCode { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionLineOfBusinessRoutingCode();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OriginationReferenceInformation")]
        public RootMessageTransactionOriginationReferenceInformation OriginationReferenceInformation { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionOriginationReferenceInformation();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PolicyTypeRoutingCode")]
        public RootMessageTransactionPolicyTypeRoutingCode PolicyTypeRoutingCode { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionPolicyTypeRoutingCode();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProcessingCycleNumber")]
        public RootMessageTransactionProcessingCycleNumber ProcessingCycleNumber { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionProcessingCycleNumber();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProcessingCycleStatus")]
        public RootMessageTransactionProcessingCycleStatus ProcessingCycleStatus { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionProcessingCycleStatus();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "QuoteDate")]
        public RootMessageTransactionQuoteDate QuoteDate { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionQuoteDate();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReferenceTransactionSequenceNumber")]
        public RootMessageTransactionReferenceTransactionSequenceNumber ReferenceTransactionSequenceNumber { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionReferenceTransactionSequenceNumber();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseAutomationLevel")]
        public RootMessageTransactionResponseAutomationLevel ResponseAutomationLevel { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionResponseAutomationLevel();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SegmentedTransactionCounter")]
        public RootMessageTransactionSegmentedTransactionCounter SegmentedTransactionCounter { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionSegmentedTransactionCounter();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SegmentedTransactionTotalPieces")]
        public RootMessageTransactionSegmentedTransactionTotalPieces SegmentedTransactionTotalPieces { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionSegmentedTransactionTotalPieces();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SegmentLevelCode")]
        public RootMessageTransactionSegmentLevelCode SegmentLevelCode { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionSegmentLevelCode();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SpecialHandling")]
        public RootMessageTransactionSpecialHandling SpecialHandling { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionSpecialHandling();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SpecialResponseOption")]
        public RootMessageTransactionSpecialResponseOption SpecialResponseOption { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionSpecialResponseOption();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SynchronizationField")]
        public RootMessageTransactionSynchronizationField SynchronizationField { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionSynchronizationField();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionCategory")]
        public RootMessageTransactionTransactionCategory TransactionCategory { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionTransactionCategory();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionDate")]
        public RootMessageTransactionTransactionDate TransactionDate { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionTransactionDate();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionEffectiveDate")]
        public RootMessageTransactionTransactionEffectiveDate TransactionEffectiveDate { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionTransactionEffectiveDate();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionFunction")]
        public RootMessageTransactionTransactionFunction TransactionFunction { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionTransactionFunction();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionImage")]
        public RootMessageTransactionTransactionImage TransactionImage { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionTransactionImage();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionSequenceNumber")]
        public RootMessageTransactionTransactionSequenceNumber TransactionSequenceNumber { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionTransactionSequenceNumber();

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionStructureStandardVersionNumber")]
        public RootMessageTransactionTransactionStructureStandardVersionNumber TransactionStructureStandardVersionNumber { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransactionTransactionStructureStandardVersionNumber();

    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionApplicationSoftwareRevisionLevel
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionAutomationLevel
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionCycleBusinessPurpose
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionDeletedTransactionDate
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionDeletedTransactionEffectiveDate
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionDeletedYear2000LogicCode
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionErrorProcessingOption
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress : IComparable<RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress>
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public int CompareTo(RootMessageTransactionFormalTransactionAddress other)
        {
            //sort desc

            if (String.Compare(this.InnerText, other.InnerText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (String.Compare(this.InnerText, other.InnerText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0)
            {
                return -1; //sort desc
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionHeader
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionInformalTransactionAddress : IComparable<RootMessageTransactionInformalTransactionAddress>
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public int CompareTo(RootMessageTransactionInformalTransactionAddress other)
        {
            //sort desc

            if (String.Compare(this.InnerText, other.InnerText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (String.Compare(this.InnerText, other.InnerText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0)
            {
                return -1; //sort desc
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionInitialTransactionMode
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionLineOfBusinessRoutingCode
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionOriginationReferenceInformation
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionPolicyTypeRoutingCode
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionProcessingCycleNumber
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionProcessingCycleStatus
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionQuoteDate
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionReferenceTransactionSequenceNumber
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionResponseAutomationLevel
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionSegmentedTransactionCounter
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionSegmentedTransactionTotalPieces
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionSegmentLevelCode
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionSpecialHandling
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionSpecialResponseOption
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionSynchronizationField
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionTransactionCategory
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionTransactionDate
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionTransactionEffectiveDate
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionTransactionFunction
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionTransactionImage
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionTransactionSequenceNumber
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class RootMessageTransactionTransactionStructureStandardVersionNumber
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "group_element")]
        public string group_element { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string InnerText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**Create a class** (name: RootMessage.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlSerialization6656
{
    public class RootMessage
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Transaction")]
        public RootMessageTransaction Transaction { get; set; } = new RootMessageTransaction();
    }
}
```

**Create a class** (name: Root.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlSerialization6656
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Root", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Root
    {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Message")]
       public RootMessage Message { get; set; } = new RootMessage();
    }
}
```

**Create a class** (name: HelperXml.cs)

Note: This class is for the serialize and deserialize methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XmlSerialization6656
{
    public class HelperXml
    {
        public static T DeserializeXMLFileToObject<T>(string xmlFilename)
        {
            //Usage: Class1 myClass1 = DeserializeXMLFileToObject<Class1>(xmlFilename);

            T rObject = default(T);

            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFilename))
                {
                    return default(T);
                }

                using (System.IO.StreamReader xmlStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(xmlFilename))
                {


                    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    rObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }

            return rObject;
        }


        public static void SerializeObjectToXMLFile(object obj, string xmlFilename)
        {
            //Usage: Class1 myClass1 = new Class1();
            //SerializeObjectToXMLFile(myClass1, xmlFilename);

            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFilename))
                {
                    return;
                }//if

                System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
                settings.Indent = true;
                settings.NewLineHandling = System.Xml.NewLineHandling.Entitize;

                using (System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(xmlFilename, settings))
                {
                    //specify namespaces
                    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                    ns.Add(string.Empty, "urn:none");

                    //create new instance
                    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

                    //write XML to file
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
//deserialize - get XML from file
Root root = HelperXml.DeserializeXMLFileToObject<Root>(xmlFilename);

//serialize - save XML to file
HelperXml.SerializeObjectToXMLFile(root, xmlFilename);
```

**Example**:

```
private void GetXmlData(string xmlFilename)
{
    //get XML
    Root root = HelperXml.DeserializeXMLFileToObject<Root>(xmlFilename);

    Debug.WriteLine("Header: " + root.Message.Transaction.Header.InnerText);

    //sort
    root.Message.Transaction.FormalTransactionAddress.Sort();

    foreach (var fta in root.Message.Transaction.FormalTransactionAddress)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("FormalTransactionAddress: group_element: " + fta.group_element + " InnerText: " + fta.InnerText);
    }

    //sort
    root.Message.Transaction.InformalTransactionAddress.Sort();

    foreach (var fta in root.Message.Transaction.InformalTransactionAddress)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("InformalTransactionAddress: group_element: " + fta.group_element + " InnerText: " + fta.InnerText);
    }
}
```