# How to save xml document file?

Tags: xml, vb.net, save

I'm relatively new to coding, especially with the vb.net language. I am trying to add a new account to my login xml database, however I can not seem to save the file. When I run my program I get the error:
**System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ExampleName\Documents\AutoMaths\bin\Debug\loginfo.xml' because it is being used by another process.'**

I am currently using the following code for my program:

```
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim addName As String = InputBox("Enter a name to add to student list")
    Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("loginfo.xml")
    Dim elmXML As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("account")
    Dim strNewAccount As String = "<name>" & addName & "</name>" +
        "<passcode>04MTH</passcode>"
    elmXML.InnerXml = strNewAccount
    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elmXML)
    doc.Save("loginfo.xml")
    proc = Process.Start("loginfo.xml", "")
    lbxStudent.Items.Clear()
    Do While xr.Read()
        If xr.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso xr.Name = "name" Then
            lbxStudent.Items.Add(xr.ReadElementContentAsString)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

If I save it under a different file name, it works, but I don't want to keep on constantly creating new files, everytime, the button is pressed. Is there a simpler way to do this and save it properly?

Comment: Which line of code gives that error? What is the `proc = Process.Start("loginfo.xml", "")` used for/needed for, does it open the file in any editor that might block other reads? Where is the `xr` variable declared/initialized?

Comment: Eliminate all code related to `Process`.

Comment: The code shows the error at the "doc.Save("loginfo.xml", "")". Also, I deleted all the process variable, and it is still not working. I also saved the xr variable as a public variable before the button sub.

Comment: Do you have any other solutions, I read somewhere that maybe I should use FileStream instead, how would I go about doing that

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605811/xmlserializer-find-element-with-name-and-attribute-value/68607179#68607179