# How to Parse Iterating elements in XML with unknown iteration

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that I need to parse and get some values from it, I need to know how to iterate for repeating items, The lineItems that are in XML, LineItem can be a different number like it can come with 1 line item or 4. So I need to parse XML and get the values of fields of any that come in.

I have 2 change the XML a bit as I cannot post the real XML here, but yes I am able to get the PurchaseOrderDate, also I only need 2 fields from this XML so no need to have a class match with it

For example, I want to get these 2 items:

```
           <BuyerPartNumber>PL123</BuyerPartNumber>
            <ItemStatus>Backorder</ItemStatus>
```

For all the line items that comes in:

```
<PurchaseOrderAck>
<Header>
    <OrderHeader>
        <TradingPartnerId>OP</TradingPartnerId>
        <OPIEReferenceID>12354</OPIEReferenceID>
        <PurchaseOrderNumber>123</PurchaseOrderNumber>
        <PurchaseOrderDate>2021-10-08</PurchaseOrderDate>
        <InternalOrderNumber>123654</InternalOrderNumber>
    </OrderHeader>
    <Address>
        <AddressTypeCode>ST</AddressTypeCode>
        <AddressName>ALBEMARLE</AddressName>
        <Address1>122 test Way</Address1>
        <Address2>Suite 104</Address2>
        <City>SUFFOLK</City>
        <State>VA</State>
        <PostalCode>12354</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Header>
<LineItems>
    <LineItem>
        <OrderLine>
            <LineSequenceNumber>0001</LineSequenceNumber>
            <BuyerPartNumber>PLPww</BuyerPartNumber>
            <VendorPartNumber>PL22</VendorPartNumber>
            <PartDescription1>Pro-Flex</PartDescription1>
            <OrderQty>1.00</OrderQty>
            <OrderQtyUOM>EA</OrderQtyUOM>
            <UnitPrice>1073.25</UnitPrice>
            <ExtendedLineAmount>1073.25</ExtendedLineAmount>
            <ItemStatus>Backorder</ItemStatus>
        </OrderLine>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
        <OrderLine>
            <LineSequenceNumber>0002</LineSequenceNumber>
            <BuyerPartNumber>I-99326</BuyerPartNumber>
            <VendorPartNumber>I-4319926</VendorPartNumber>
            <PartDescription1>ICEROSS</PartDescription1>
            <OrderQty>2.00</OrderQty>
            <OrderQtyUOM>EA</OrderQtyUOM>
            <UnitPrice>292.410000</UnitPrice>
            <ExtendedLineAmount>584.82</ExtendedLineAmount>
            <ItemStatus>Released</ItemStatus>
        </OrderLine>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
        <OrderLine>
            <LineSequenceNumber>0003</LineSequenceNumber>
            <BuyerPartNumber>I-C880</BuyerPartNumber>
            <VendorPartNumber>I-8820</VendorPartNumber>
            <PartDescription1>ICEROSS D</PartDescription1>
            <OrderQty>2.00</OrderQty>
            <OrderQtyUOM>EA</OrderQtyUOM>
            <UnitPrice>277.830000</UnitPrice>
            <ExtendedLineAmount>555.66</ExtendedLineAmount>
            <ItemStatus>Released</ItemStatus>
        </OrderLine>
    </LineItem>
</LineItems>
```

and this is my class that want value in:

```
  public class PurchaseOrderModel
     {
    public string PurchaseOrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<int> BuyerPartNumber{ get; set; }
    public List<string> ItemStatus{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid xml from what I see. Also you should model your classes to match the xml. Then you can simply deserialize to your class...

Comment: Have you figured out how to get PurchaseOrderDate yet? I assume not since you have it defined as an `int`, but if you have some code we can help you based on the API you are already using since there are various ways to parse XML.

Comment: The following may be helpul: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605811/xmlserializer-find-element-with-name-and-attribute-value/68607179#68607179

Comment: @Trevor I only need 2 fields from it.

Comment: @Crowcoder - Yes I was able, sorry I try to change the XML a bit in my question, that was miss spelling,

Comment: `I only need 2 fields from it`, for now. I'm trying to say you could deserialize this xml to a strong typed class, then you have anything you need; it's the way to go. Also what determines what object you go after if there could be more than one `LineItem` and or `OrderLine`?

Comment: @Trevor Nothing would determine how many I get, XML that I get maybe has 1 line-item, maybe 3, I need to iterate to get the value if for example, it if sending 3, I need all 3 items.

Comment: @Alma can you post the exact xml declaration that is valid; make sure to change values.

Comment: @Trevor - I posted exact XML,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little LINQ-to-XML to get you started:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var col = doc.Root
             .Elements("LineItems")
             .Elements("LineItem")
             .Elements("OrderLine")
             .Select(e => new 
             {
                 PurchaseOrderDate = doc.Root.Element("Header").Element("OrderHeader").Element("PurchaseOrderDate").Value,
                 BuyerPartNumber = e.Element("BuyerPartNumber").Value,
                 ItemStatus = e.Element("ItemStatus").Value
             });
foreach (var item in col)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could utilize the XmlDocument's GetElementsByTagName() method like the example below:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Create the XmlDocument.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("books.xml");

        //Display all the book titles.
        XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("title");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
        }
    }
}
```